# How to sort a dictionary based on date key value

Tags: c#, sorting, date, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary, which is a nested dictionary. I want to sort it according to the date and time provided in the dictionary. how to do this is c#. Here is my code

```
foreach (var user in Load_User)
            {
                
                if(user.Value.Projects[0].type=="0")
                {
                    print("Standard User");
                    
                    
                     _Standard_User.Add(user.Key, new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
                               { "Email", user.Value.Email },
                               { "age",user.Value.age},
                               {"userName", user.Value.userName},
                               {"mobile", user.Value.mobile},
                               {"instagram_handle",user.Value.instagram_handle},
                               { "City_Of_Residence", user.Value.City_Of_Residence },
                               { "nationality", user.Value.nationality },
                               { "No_of_Votes", user.Value.No_of_Votes.ToString()},
                               {"Brief",user.Value.Projects[0].Brief},
                               {"Creation_Date", user.Value.Projects[0].Creation_Date},
                               {"Creation_Time", user.Value.Projects[0].Creation_Time},
                               {"type", user.Value.Projects[0].type},
                               {"localId",user.Value.localId},
                               {"thumbnail_image",user.Value.Projects[0].thumbnail_image}
                            });

                }
```

Comment: [`SortedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-6.0)? Dictionaries generally don't have an order, because you use them to look up values by their key, so order is usually meaningless.

Comment: How about `_Standard_User.OrderBy(userKvp => userKvp.Value["Creation_Date"]);`?

Comment: is there any way to re-arrange them in  decenting them order based on date

Comment: @Oliver this message is  showing 'Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using LINQ (make sure to include the `System.Linq` namespace):

```
_Standard_User.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Value["Creation_Date"]).Add(TimeSpan.Parse(x.Value["Creation_Time"])))
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

This will return the dictionary, sorted by both the creation date and time. This expects the `Creation_Date` to be parseable by `Convert.ToDateTime` (a format like 2022-09-30), and `Creation_Time` to be parseable by `TimeSpan.Parse` (a format like 10:38).

If you have the exact format, you can utilize `TimeSpan.ParseExact` which will bypass any culture issues:

```
_Standard_User.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Value["Creation_Date"], "yyyy-MM-dd", null).Add(TimeSpan.Parse(x.Value["Creation_Time"])))
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

The snippet above will be functionally equal to the previous snippet, but it will expect dates in the format of year-month-day.

Comment: Thanks for the replay it showing a message. my date formate is 2022-09-29 and time is 14:51:41 
DataHandler Error:System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  at System.DateTimeParse.Parse (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] s, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtf

Comment: Seems like a localization (culture) issue, as it works on my system configuration. If you have the exact format the date string will be, you can use `ParseExact`, which is safer than `Convert.ToDateTime`: `DateTime.ParseExact(x.Value["Creation_Date"], "yyyy-MM-dd", null)`

Comment: it is running without any error but its not sorting

Comment: @Savad Are you sure you're assigning the value to the `_Standard_User` field/property? This snippet returns the sorted dictionary, it doesn't do it in-place. Also, this sorts it in ascending order, you may be looking for `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: Ya I am sure because, when i am calling the field i am getting the date but is not sorted

Comment: Does the dictionary get modified in any way? If not, that means that you are either discarding the output of `ToDictionary`, or the snippet isn't being called at all.

Comment: no its not modifed in any means

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248465/discussion-between-ascpixi-and-savad).